# Breaking nested loops and iteration

Tags: python, nested-loops, break

So here's simple structure of my code:

```
while condition:
    for i in range(num):
        for j in range(num):
            if arr[i][j] == something:
                #DO SOMETHING
                #ESCAPE
```

I want to escape only the for loops and start over the iteration from arr[0][0] inside the while loop.

It also has to avoid checking the same value that was checked in the previous loop.

For example, if arr[1][1] == something so it goes over the if statement, for the next iteration, it should start from arr[0][0] again and skip checking arr[1][1].

I'm struggling with break statements and the skipping part.

Answer (score -1):

```py
checked_indices = set()  # Set to store the checked indices

while condition:
    for i in range(num):
        for j in range(num):
            if (i, j) not in checked_indices and arr[i][j] == something:
                # DO SOMETHING
                checked_indices.add((i, j))  # Add the checked index to the set
                break  # Escape the innermost for loop
        else:
            continue  # Continue to the next iteration of the outer for loop
        break  # Escape the outer for loop
    else:
        break  # Escape the while loop

# Continue with the rest of your code
```

- `checked_indices` set is used to keep track of the `indices` that have been checked. If an index `(i, j)` has already been checked, it will be skipped in the next iteration.
- `break` statements are used to escape the for loops when a match is found and to continue with the next iteration of the outer for loop or while loop when necessary.

Comment: While this works, this is very confusing to read and understand.